# Substring_index between 2 delimiters

Tags: mysql

I am trying to isolate a string in my database that is located between 2 \ 's

Z:\PHR Archives\2016\08-August\2016-08-14 Grasshopper Newfoundland\0059 - Jimmy - SGB05-09 - Bon Jovi - Runaway.mp3

above is a sample row --  I need "2016-08-14 Grasshopper Newfoundland"

Basically everything after the 4th \  up until the next \

I tried

```
 substring_index(substring_index(filename, '\\', -3), '\\', 1)
```

But it's only working on some rows --

Comment: which rows it is not working, can you put some example

Comment: Thank you for the reply -- Some of my data, has an extra layer of / 's  '2019-08-04 Grasshopper Too', 'Z:\PHR Archives\2019\08-August\2019-08-04 Grasshopper Too\incomplete\Chris Cox, Lee Dagger f.-Ollie James - Messin' With My Mind (Club Mix).mp3'    I editted the code to select substring_index(substring_index(filename, '\\', 5), '\\', -1) and I think it worked